# Cast object returned from method to subclass

Tags: c#, methods, return-value, subclass

I have a method that returns an object of type `Bucket`:

```
Bucket Dispense(string typeName);
```

I have a class named `Widget` that subclasses `Bucket`:

```
public class Widget : Bucket {  }
```

I want to do this:

```
Widget w = Controller.Dispense('widget');
```

Which I think should be possible, given that a `Widget` is a `Bucket`. I could cast the return type of `Dispense(string)` to type `Widget`, but I'd much rather do this without a cast. Is there a way of aliasing the `Bucket` and `Widget` types?

Comment: I'm the downvoter, you cannot cast Bucket to widget. You need to understand OOPs concepts

Comment: @Raj Maybe you could help me do that instead of downvoting me?

Comment: I usually write my "factory" methods as generic methods which have a type parameter, so `Controller.Dispense<Widget>("widget")` would return a Widget (likely using a cast inernally) or otherwise cause some prescribed behavior (e.g. return null or throw an Exception) if a non-Widget was somehow created.

Comment: But no, "aliasing" is not possible like this. To avoid any sort of cast *here*, `Bucket b = ..` (or use an interface).

Comment: I like the idea of using an interface. So I'd just create an `IBucket` interface and make sure `Widget` implemented it, then rewrite `Dispense` to return an `IBucket`?

Comment: As long as you put it in an `IBucket`-typed variable (it still can't be assigned to a `Widget`-typed variable without refinement, like a cast).

Answer (score 3):

You could get some of what you're looking for using generics:

```
public class BucketDispenser
{
    public TBucket Dispense<TBucket>(string typeName) where TBucket : Bucket
    {
        Bucket widget= new Widget();
        // or
        Bucket widget = new OtherWidget();

        return (TBucket)(object)widget;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        var disp = new BucketDispenser();
        Widget widget = disp.Dispense<Widget>("widget");
        OtherWidget otherWidget = disp.Dispense<OtherWidget>("otherWidget");
    }
 }
```

Comment: In the `return` line, is it necessary to first cast the widget variable to object?

Answer (score 2):

Another simple option is you can use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) to avoid casting, it will bypass compile-time type checking:

```
dynamic w = Controller.Dispense('widget');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).  This is defined within the `Bucket` class as follows:

```
public static implicit operator Widget(Bucket bucket)
{
    // return the typecast Widget (can also perform any conversion logic here if necessary)
    return (Widget)bucket;
}
```

Now you can perform the cast "implicitly" as it were:

```
Bucket b = new Bucket();
Widget w = b;
```

**Note** use with caution as per pst's comment, and also from the MSDN link:

> Conversion operators can be explicit or implicit. Implicit conversion operators are easier to use, but explicit operators are useful when you want users of the operator to be aware that a conversion is taking place.

Comment: But this is just black magic about the same non-typesafe construct .. (when bucket *really isn't* a Widget). Given these two options, I'd always pick the explicit cast.

Comment: That is, I think the poster is looking for something more.

Comment: @pst you could be right.  The op's question isn't really, ahem, *explicit* about the overarching purpose.